# How to break Travis CI build if Appium/Mocha tests fail?

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, mocha.js, appium, travis-ci

I have a Travis CI project which builds an iOS app then starts Appium and runs tests with Appium/Mocha.
The problem is that even though the Mocha tests fail and throw exception, the shell script which runs them via Gulp still exits with 0 and the build is deemed passing.

How can I make the build break/fail when the Mocha tests fail?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I managed to make this work:

1. Instead of running the Mocha tests via Gulp, run them directly from the shell script
2. Save the output to mocha.log besides displaying on stdout

`./node_modules/.bin/mocha --reporter spec "appium/hybrid/*uat.js" 2>&1 | tee mocha.log`

3. Check mocha.log for the string " failing" and exit with 1 if found

.

```
if grep -q " failing" mocha.log; then
   exit 1
fi
```

The `exit 1` will make the Travis build fail.